# selecting query from one file

Tags: php

so i have some kind of code on a page like this

```html
<?php
$a = $_GET['act'];
if ($a){
include('show.php');
} else {
include('show.php');
}
?>
```

and on other page like this

```html
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT * from DONE ";
$b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql2);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
.......
?>

<?php
$sql3 = "SELECT * from ONGOING ";
$b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql3);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
.......
?>
```

my question , is it possible when the condition is met it execute the first query and when the condition doesn't met it execute the second query , when both of the query placed on same page ?

Comment: it will fire both query

Comment: when the page is load

Comment: you can add the sql query there itself why putting it in another page..

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding condition in main page add it in included page so that your query can executed condition wise
**Main page**

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET['act'];
    include('show.php');
?>
```

**show.php**

```
<?php
if ($a){
$sql2 = "SELECT * from DONE ";
$b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql2);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
//.......
}
else
{
$sql3 = "SELECT * from ONGOING ";
$b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql3);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
//.......
}
?>
```

Comment: well, this one surely is on point , thanks . accepted answer as reward :)

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely why [PHP has functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). In your included file organize those two things into separate chunks of code:

```
<?php
function fromDone($con) {
  $b = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from DONE ");
  $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
  .......
}

function fromOngoing($con) {
  $b = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT * from ONGOING");
  $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
  .......
}
?>
```

Then in your main file you can do this:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['act']) {
  fromDone($con);
} else {
  fromOngoing($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Though with a function `$con` would be undefined. Variable scope issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = $_GET['act'];
if($a)
$sql = "SELECT * from DONE ";
else
$sql = "SELECT * from ONGOING ";

$b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
.......
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to tell which query to run.

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET['act'];
    if ($a){
        include('show.php');
        $code = 1;
    }
    else {
        include('show.php');
        $code = 2;
    }
?>



<?php 
    if($code == 1){
        $sql = "SELECT * from DONE ";
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT * from ONGOING ";
    }
?>

<?php
    $b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql);
    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
    .......
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['act'];
if ($a){
include('show.php?condition=ok');
} else {
include('show.php?condition=notok');
}
?>
```

and on other page like this

```
<?php
if($_GET['condition']=='ok')
{
$sql2 = "SELECT * from DONE ";
$b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql2);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
.......
}
else if($_GET['condition']=='notok') {

$sql3 = "SELECT * from ONGOING ";
$b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql3);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
.......
} else {  

//other stuff

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Main.php

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET['act'];
    if($a)
       $table='tableone';
    else
       $table='tabletwo';

    include('show.php?table=$table');
?>
```

show.php

```
<?php

  $sql = "SELECT * from ".$_GET['table'];
  $b = mysqli_query ($con,$sql);
  $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($b);
?>
```

Comment: we can pass table name fom main file to show file according to condition. if we pass Table name then no required two query. we can just make one query and add Table name which we get from URL